# Change colorPrimary and colorAccent programmatically for use in ContextThemeWrapper

Tags: android-view, android-theme, android-context, android-viewgroup

I'm working on a live event app for a client. There are about 20 view containers that make heavy use of `colorPrimary` and `colorAccent` for coloring the views.

The client has just now decided that those colors should be different for each event.

---

Is there any way for me to use `ContextThemeWrapper` to simply inject the `colorAccent` and `colorPrimary` received from the backend? That way, when I start `EventActivity`, I can just put in the correct colors, and those would propagate all the way down to the activity's `View`, `Fragment`, and `Dialog` children.

---

If that's not possible, I guess I will have to go through each `View` one by one in Java and set the appropriate colors. That's tedious but easy. What's not easy are my shapes defined in XML. For instance, I have a `drawable` that I use as a button background which is simply a 1dp stroke on a rectangle with rounded corners. The color of the stroke is `colorAccent`. How would I go about changing that at runtime?